# how should javascript array control be

Tags: javascript

there is an array data as below.
I will have a `nav.` operation on the incoming data data in the array, otherwise I will print the data it is, I wonder how can I do this?`

`title: item.title,`

if `item.title` in the incoming data nav. If there is
Let this.$t(item.title) pass the print check. but if there is no `nav.` then check if `this.$t(item.title)`

```
menu_items: [
        {
          title: 'nav.home',
          path: '/',
          Index: 0
        },
        {
          title: 'nav.gallery',
          path: '/gallery',
          order: 10
        },
        {
          title: 'nav.contact',
          path: '/contact',
          order: 12
        },
        {
          title: 'hello',
          path: '/hello',
          order: 13
        },
        {
          title: 'hello2',
          path: '/hello2',
          order: 14
        }
      ]
```

```
menuItem() {
      return this.menu_items.map(item => {
        return {
          title: item.title,
          path: item.path,
          children: item.children,
          order: item.order
        }
      }).sort((a, b) => a.order - b.order)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first thing you need to do is search `item.title` `item.title.search('nav.')`
If there is no `nav.` in the data after checking, if `item.title` exists, `this.$t(item.title)`

```
menuItem() {
      return this.menu_items.map(item => {
        return {
          title: item.title.search('nav.') ? item.title : this.$t(item.title),
          path: item.path,
          children: item.children,
          order: item.order
        }
      }).sort((a, b) => a.order - b.order)
    }
```